# cabal install hsparql error

Tags: haskell, sparql, cabal

Im trying to install hsparql, cabal version 1.22.1.1

```
cabal install hsparql
```

gives

```
Could not find module `Network.URI'
It is a member of the hidden package `network-uri-2.6.0.1'.
Perhaps you need to add `network-uri' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed to install hsparql-0.2.5
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hsparql-0.2.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

but

```
cabal install network-uri
```

shows

```
All the requested packages are already installed:
network-uri-2.6.0.1
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Wait, when you try `cabal install hsparql` you get that error message? Are you using a sandbox? I usually see that error message when using sandboxes and I haven't added the mentioned package to my cabal file.

Comment: @danem no I'm not using sandbox

Comment: And if you fire up GHCi, you can import Network.URI?